# How to manage RTL languages phones in English application

Tags: android, right-to-left, left-to-right

I am programming an Android application. This application isn't translated to any right to left language (like Arabic or Hebrew). I've noticed that right to left language people has it in English, but with right to left layout. The drawer menu is on the right instead of the left and the text is right aligned.

What is the good practice to manage this? Should I let the RTL layout because they are used to it or should I force LTR layout because the app is in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re not supporting RTL languages you should not support RTL layouts (LTR languages looks pretty bad in RTL languages).

Just add `android:supportRtl="false"` attribute in your manifest's `application` tag.

It should solve it.

Even though `false` is the default value, one of your dependencies can override it to `true` if you don't set it explicitly.

Confirm that this is the issue by checking the final merged manifest if `android:supportRtl` is `true`.

Comment: If some day I translate the app in one RTL language, but not in the others, is there a way to activate `supportRtl` for that language but not for the others?

Comment: In case you decide to support RTL - the layout direction will be determined automatically according to the actual language that is used. So, you only need to adapt your layouts to use “start” instead of “left” and “end” instead of “right”.

Comment: Also, you can force RTL layout from developer options to test it with every language